# Find last occurence of a string using findstr on windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a text file with a string occurs multiple lines. I want to get the line where this is the last occurrence of the string. I could find all occurrences using below command but I want only last occurrence in single line command.

```
findstr /C:"Apple Ball Cat" Book.txt
```

Can someone guide me if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FOR command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) from command line:

```
(for /F "delims=" %G in ('findstr /C:"Apple Ball Cat" Book.txt') do @set "lastoccur=%G")&set lastoccur
```

From a batch script:

```
@echo off
set "lastoccur="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('findstr /C:"Apple Ball Cat" Book.txt') do set "lastoccur=%%G"
set lastoccur
echo "%lastoccur%"
```

In `echo` command are (possible, supposed) [`cmd`-poisonous characters escaped using double quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).